# Two layout visibility problem in one activity

Tags: android, xml

I have two linear layouts e.g. L1 and L2.
I put them on a single activity.
Outside these two layouts, I have a radio button from which I'm controlling visibility. At a time only 1 should be visible.
It perfectly working but the problem is,

Two linear layouts are stacked over each other. So when I invisible the upper layout(L1) then it shows white space in that area.

So the L1 gets invisible but space is still occupied by itself.

I want to take that area from L1 so that L2 replaces it.

[Note: This is just a concept so I thought the XML code is not required. But still, if you need I will update it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the visibility to `invisible`, set it at `gone`. The different is that, in `gone` mode, components are not part of the visual tree anymore

Answer (score 1):

When you turn the visibility to `invisible`, you can't see the layout but it will still there and occupying the space. It is similar to the `layout.setAlpha(0f);`. When you use `setAlpha(0f);`, the user can interact with all the views inside that layout i.e, `Button` inside layout will not visible but can be clicked. While `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` doesn't allow to do so.

When you turn the visibility to `gone`, the layout becomes not visible (act as height and width become `0`). But it stills present in its parent view. It doesn't mean that it will be removed from the parent layout.

Comment: The previous question solved my problem and I got the difference between INVISIBLE and GONE. But during INVISIBLE I can still touch a button explored my knowledge. So thanks for that!!! : )